# Is there a way to build pytorch without including CUDA in the wheel itself?

Tags: build, pytorch

The official pytorch wheels have become huge (>2GB). It seems the main reason is that CUDA is included in the wheel itself so that users don't need to install it separately.

Suppose I already have installed the correct CUDA on my machine, is there a way to compile pytorch so that it links to an already existing CUDA installation?
In the end I would like to have a pytorch wheel that weights more or less like the CPU-only version.